# What sort of aberration is this?

Tags: optics

I am creating a projector, for the purpose of explanation given I cannot take a photograph of my projected image, let's say I would like to project the following image:
[image: ideal image]

The image I get however resembles the following:
[image: actual image]

That is to say the light seems to diverge more the further it is from the centre. My inclination from what I've read is to say that it's some kind of astigmatism but I'm not overly familiar with optics and the different kinds of aberrations. Additionally, how might this be corrected?

Comment: This may be due to too high [Petzval field curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petzval_field_curvature).

Comment: This may be spherical aberration, but you only showed images along one axis, so that's not a certainty.

Comment: @Ruslan I think you're right, I don't have an iris I can use atm but reducing the intensity of the light does seem to improve things significantly

Comment: @DavidWhite Sorry about that, just to clarify this issue appears equally regardless how you rotate the image to be projected given the same origin

Comment: In that case, I would say you have spherical aberration.